# ArgumentException not thrown in C# test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm currently testing an `Active Directory` Method that fetches users in Active Directory. My test method is supposed to look for an exception thrown when the string I pass as argument is using illegal characters. Here is my tested method:

```
public List<ADProperties> SearchUserByName(string name)
{
    try
    {
        //Active Directory properties loading here
        if(condition)
        { 
            //Condition throws ArgumentException because of invalid AD Filter using characters
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AE caught : "+ae.ToString());
    }
}
```

I should precise that the line where the exception occurs interrupts my program at this precise point. 
     Here is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void SearchUserByNameIllegalCharsTest()
{
    string generateChars = new string('*', 10);
    List<ADProperties> test3 = adManager.SearchUserByName(generateChars);
    //ArgumentException is thrown on this call
}
```

Even though the `ArgumentException` is thrown, my test still failed, saying the method has not thrown the expected Exception. What am I not seeing here?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because you're catching the exception within `SearchUserByName`, the test method has no knowledge of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not throw that exception anywhere. With your catch statement, nothing tells the outer block or scope that an exception occurred. You can either add a throw after the `Console.WriteLine`

```
public List<ADProperties> SearchUserByName(string name)
{
    try
    {
        //Active Directory properties loading here
        if(condition)
        { 
            //Condition throws ArgumentException because of invalid AD Filter using characters
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AE caught : "+ae.ToString());
        throw ae;
    }
}
```

or remove the try-catch block

```
public List<ADProperties> SearchUserByName(string name)
{
        //Active Directory properties loading here
        if(condition)
        { 
            //Condition throws ArgumentException because of invalid AD Filter using characters
            return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your method is catching the exception without re-throwing it. To be able to see the exception in the Unit Test you should have a *throw* statement in your catch:

```
try {
       //Active Directory properties loading here
       if(condition){ //Condition throws ArgumentException because of invalid AD Filter using characters
          return null;
       }
   }catch(ArgumentException ae){
      Console.WriteLine("AE caught : "+ae.ToString());
      throw;
   }
```

Comment: Or you don't need to catch it at all, the test framework should log it anyway.

Comment: @RobinSalih Because in this case it is an unchecked exception?